# balloon yandex map vue при рендере страницы

Tags: vue.js

Как открывать balloon при рендере страницы, а не только при клике? Использую vue.Пробовал по-всякому, но не могу понять как получить balloon у маркера. Его нет, но если создать самостоялень через :balloon, то есть хоть какие-то сподвиги. Через ссылку ref=map можно получить балун, но он будет другим не относящийся к marker.

```
<div v-if="activeSalon && activeSalon.coordinates" class="registry__map">
        <yandex-map
          ref="map"
          :settings="settings"
          :coords="activeSalon.coordinates"
          :zoom="15"
          style="width: 100%; height: 400px"
          @map-was-initialized="onMapInitialized"
        >
          <ymap-marker
            ref="marker"
            markerId="viktoria"
            :icon="viktoriaIcon"
            :coords="activeSalon.coordinates"
            :balloon="{
              header: 'dasdasd',
              body: 'dasdasd',
            }"
          >
          </ymap-marker>
        </yandex-map>
      </div>
```